# Opening notification on specific index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, xcode12

I have an app with multiple folders. One of the folders is set with a location reminder. When I enter the region I get a notification alert. Up to this, it's working well.
Now when I tap the notification the App opens but I want to open the specific folder that triggers on entering the region. How can I implement this to work?

Should I use the notification delegate method?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler API_AVAILABLE(ios(7.0));
```

If so should I get a new certificate with Push notification enabled? Please suggest me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the folder path into userInfo with a custom key can help. Delegate method is depends on the framework you are using. It can be implemented as a local notification, so the certificate is not necessary.

Comment: Can you help me with a few codes on what to call? I think I am going in the right direction as you suggested. Trying to use the user info and get a callback through this method.

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler

Comment: UNMutableNotificationContent has a  userInfo property: 
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.title = @"Hello";
content.userInfo = @{@"Key": @"some value"}; // <---- setup custom info here

// after setup the content, pass it to notification request
UNNotificationRequest *req = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"test-id" content:content trigger:trigger];